# Is space $C[0,1]$ is Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

> Is space $C[0,1]$ is Hausdorff?

I just started studying metric spaces. I encountered the Hausdroff space definition. I wanted to construct a space which does not have that property.

I thought of $C[0,1]$ as candidate. Because we can define 2 distant function which agree at single point.

SO  It is not possible to haved isjoint open balls.

Is my argument correct?

Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: Note that $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$ is just a set. Which topology do you have in mind?

Comment: Sir ,topology generated by supremum metric f

Comment: Any metric space is Hausdorff. You can take it as an easy exercise to prove that.

Comment: Ohh I got for distantness sup(f,g)>$\epsilon$ which is not here.Thanks a lot

Comment: Now if you want to find a space which is not Hausdorff then the easiest example is a set $X$ with cardinality at least $2$ with the trivial topology. If you want a more interesting example then look at an infinite set $X$ with the co-finite topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $C[0,1]$ by itself is not a topological space. If you are taking about this set with the standard metric $d(f,g)=\sup \{|f(x)-g(x)|:0\leq x \leq 1\}$ then it is Hausdorff because any metric space is Hausdorff. [ If $x \neq y$  and $r=d(x,y)$ then $B(x,\frac r 2)$ and $B(y,\frac r 2)$ are disjoint open sets containing $x$ and $y$ respectively.